# Disallow subdomain url using robots.txt

Tags: subdomain, robots.txt

i would like to ask you a question...

i have a domain kiosban.com and store.kiosban.com..

and i want to disallow

```
store.kiosban.com/template/*
```

And i have this on my store.kiosban.com/robots.txt

but when i look at google webmaster tools... on health menu >> Blocked Url, i got

```
robots.txt file                         Blocked URLs    Downloaded  Status
http://www.store.kiosban.com/robots.txt -             Never
```

Did i do something wrong??

Answer (score 0):

`www.store.kiosban.com` and `store.kiosban.com` are different hosts. You should provide a robots.txt on both hosts, or even better, 301-redirect one form to the other one.

But that doesn’t seem to be the issue in your case. It looks like Google just needs some time to crawl your site resp. its robots.txt.